# Priting each iteration to label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Trying to print out each iteration of Bubblesort to the label text to show on the screen rather than console.

I tried to assign the label text each time the array is updated but it only shows the last version of the array which is the sorted one

On screen print:

[image: on screen print]

What I want to print n the label:

[image: what i want to print on the label]

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!

    public func bubbleSort<T> (_ arrays: [T], _ comparison: (T,T) -> Bool) -> [T]  {
        var array = arrays

        for i in 0..<array.count {
            for j in 1..<array.count-i {
                if comparison(array[j], array[j-1]) {
                    let tmp = array[j-1]
                    array[j-1] = array[j]
                    array[j] = tmp
                    print(array) // prints the array after each iteration to the console
                // inserting Label2.text = "\(array)" doesnt work as I intend it to. 
                }
            }
        }


        return array
    }

    public func bubbleSort<T> (_ elements: [T]) -> [T] where T: Comparable {
        return bubbleSort(elements, <)
    }

}
```

Comment: That's not a single label anymore. Probably best to use a UITableView, containing multiple labels.

Comment: Were you wanting to show all steps on the screen at the same time (similar to the console output), or animate the label showing it change until it is sorted?

Comment: @vacawama , yes just print the console output to the label or textview. No need for animation at this stage.

Comment: I like Alexander's suggestion.  Use a tableView to display the results.  Create a `[String]` called `steps`  to hold the data for the table.  At each step, append `steps.append("\(array)")`.  Use that as the dataSource for your tableView displaying `cell.label.text = steps[indexPath.row]`.

Comment: If you want to add multiple lines to a label in a loop then look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134482/9223839)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good place to use a `tableView` to display the data.

1. Add a `UITableView` to your `ViewController`.  Add a **Basic** style prototype cell with `"cell"` as the reuse identifier.
2. Attach the tableView in the Storyboard to `@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!`.
3. Set up the `tableView.delegate` and `tableView.dataSource` in `viewDidLoad()`.
4. Add a property `var steps = [String]` to your `ViewController`.
5. At each step of the bubbleSort, append the array to the `steps`: `steps.append("\(array)")`.
6. In `numberOfRowsInSection()`, `return steps.count`.
7. In `cellForRowAt()`, set `cell.textLabel?.text = steps[indexPath.row]`.
8. Use a `didSet` property observer for `steps` to call `tableView.reloadData()`.

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return steps.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = steps[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    var steps = [String]() {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    public func bubbleSort<T> (_ arrays: [T], _ comparison: @escaping (T,T) -> Bool) -> [T]  {
        var array = arrays

        for i in 0..<array.count {
            for j in 1..<array.count-i {
                if comparison(array[j], array[j-1]) {
                    let tmp = array[j-1]
                    array[j-1] = array[j]
                    array[j] = tmp
                    print(array) // prints the array after each iteration to the console
                    steps.append("\(array)")
                }
            }
        }

        return array
    }

    public func bubbleSort<T> (_ elements: [T]) -> [T] where T: Comparable {
        return bubbleSort(elements, <)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func go(button: UIButton) {
        steps = []
        _ = bubbleSort([33, 45, 25, 356, 5, 90, 14])
    }
}
```